# I haven't got wlan0

Tags: wireless, ethernet, aircrack-ng

I am new with Gnu/Linux operating systems and specially with recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. I wanted to learn something about WLAN-s security and y tried to work with "aircrack-ng". I have a Samsung N150plus Laptop and when I was trying this, with "macchanger", "kismet" and "aircrack-ng" already installed, I see that I haven't any "wlan0", replacing it I believe that is "eth1" and I can't work with that.
I post you a code from terminal:

```
enter code hereroot@Samsung-N150p:/home/samsung# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"WLAN_71"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 00:02:CF:C0:95:29   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
root@Samsung-N150p:/home/samsung# airmon-ng start eth1


Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
823 avahi-daemon
824 avahi-daemon
856 NetworkManager
1013    wpa_supplicant
6795    dhclient
Process with PID 6795 (dhclient) is running on interface eth1


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth1        Unknown     wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)

root@Samsung-N150p:/home/samsung# ifconfig mon0 down
mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

And I don't have any problem with wireless connections, in this moment I'm writing that from the Laptop with Wifi and works perfectly.
Help me please.
Thank you for reading ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You juste have to replace `wlan0` with `eth1`.

For example if you want to change your wireless interface mode to monitor mode just do

```
# airmon-ng start eth1
```

You can have some problems with the aircrack-ng suite, if so it will probably be because your wireless interface doesn't support monitor mode and not because it name isn't `wlan0`.

Comment: I post another terminal lines, what do you think about?

Comment: When you use the aircrack-ng suite you need to stop / kill every process that use your wireless interface. In your case, you would have to stop avahi-daemon, NetworkManager, wpa_supplicant and dhclient. 

But your main problem is that your wireless card driver doesn't support the monitor mode, so you'll not be able to crack wifi with your current card.