# why does mon0 give Error : No Such Device?

Tags: wireless

[image: airmor-ng start wlan0]

it does not work. Then I Use this code.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion libnl-dev
cd /opt/
sudo svn co http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/ aircrack-ng
cd aircrack-ng
sudo make
sudo make install
```

but don't solve this error. What can I solve this problems?

`“wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device” .`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I haven't got wlan0](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397807/i-havent-got-wlan0)

Comment: maybe this pace help you http://airodump.net/intuitive-wifi-hacking-gui-ubuntu-linux/